# WordPress sites got auto upgraded

Tags: automatic-updates

With the release of WordPress 4.0.1 all my sites got auto upgraded even if none visited them and all those websites are behind browser authentication.

My sites are not broken but I am just curious to know how WordPress auto-upgrades the sites which are behind browser authentication.

Comment: Have you read: http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates ?

Comment: Now WordPress auto-upgrade itself for minor updates. You can disable it though if you want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the update to occur, the site would have had to receive some form of traffic. Any traffic which loaded WordPress would do. Alternatively, anything which started the wp-cron.php process would trigger the update as well, like if you have it set to run that with a normal cron.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer. I was thinking of the same procress but the problem is the sites were upgraded in the midnight and we were not working at that time. I believe, in order to trigger wp-cron.php, someone has to visit the site. Is that right?

Comment: Someone or something has to make an http request which starts WordPress, yes. Doesn't have to be a person. Anything which hits the server will do the job.